# SQL Error when using PHPUnit

Tags: php, sql, laravel, phpunit

Phpunit detects an error on my query

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "(": syntax error (SQL:
    select * from "forms"
    where "factual_checkout_at" is null
    and "plan_checkout_at" >= ?
    and CONCAT(UPPER(RIGHT(name, 3)), id) = ?
    and "forms"."deleted_at" is null and "forms"."type" in (?, ?, ?) limit 1
)
```

I'm trying to get a form with given code. (In this case I combine last 3 digit of user's name with their id).

The problem is, my app runs well with this query, the transaction goes well, but not on phpunit.

Here's the method to get that form (laravel):

```
$form = Form::whereNull('factual_checkout_at')
            ->where('plan_checkout_at', '>=', Carbon::today())
            ->whereRaw('CONCAT(UPPER(RIGHT(name, 3)), id) = ?', $code)
            ->firstOrFail();
return new FormResource($form);
```

What did I miss?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what database driver are you using in for your unit testing?

Comment: i use sqlite for unit test

Comment: `CONCAT` keyword is not available for SQLite.

Comment: Well, how fool I am. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did miss on my query syntax, because I use sqlite on my test.

Changed the query to

```
... and upper(substr(name, -3)) || id = ? ...
```

fixed that.
Thanks to @Wreigh!